# How to get the id when call add in one step in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know to get id:

```
String cityId = db.collection("cities").document().getId();
db.collection("cities").document(cityId).set(city);
```

But is more easy:

```
db.collection("cities").add(city);
```

But how to get id? It not work `.add(city).getId()`. No information in docs.

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener?

Comment: Thanks, no how to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the id when call add in one step in Firestore?

There is no way in which you can get the document id in a single step, as you do when using a `document()` call. To solve this, you should add a complete listener. Try this:

```
db.collection("cities").add(city).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentReference document = task.getResult();
            if (document != null) {
                String id = document.getId(); //Do what you need to do with the document id
                Log.d(TAG, id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```