# How to get the biggest population in a city using Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please help me with this. I have this like in docs:

```
cities
 \
  - San Francisco
        \
         - "population": 860000
 \
  - Los Angeles
        \
         - "population": 3900000
 \
  - San Francisco
        \
         - "population": 680000
```

How to display city with biggest population in emulator? I use:

```
    cities = new ArrayList<>();
    db.collection("cities").get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                int population = Integer.valueOf(document.getData().get("population").toString());
                cities.add(population);
            }
            Collections.sort(cities);
            }
        }
        });
```

But is not working. How to know from list the biggest population city?

Comment: what's your expected output? you want to get the city name? Right now your are just sorting the population number, which is int

Comment: thanks, yes Los Angeles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hot to get biggest population in city in Firestore?

Simply by using a query that looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference citiesRef = rootRef.collection("cities");
Query query = citiesRef.orderBy("population", Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1);
```

The `orderBy()` method is called to order the cities descending, according to the `population` property and `limit(1)` is called to limit the results to only one city, the city with the highest population.

**Edit:**

Knowing from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114938/how-to-get-the-id-when-call-add-in-one-step-in-firestore) of yours (to which I have already provided you an answer), the way you are adding the data to the database is by using the `add()` method.
This means that everytime you are adding a new city, you are generating a new document id. With other words, the id of the document is a random generated key and **not** the name of the city as I see in your schema.

So if you are using the example from the official documentation, beside the `population` property you might also have the `name` of the city.

To display the name of the city with the biggest population, please use the following lines of code:

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document != null) {
                    String name = document.getString("name");
                    Log.d(TAG, name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Los Angeles
```

Comment: Why do you say is not working, do you have an error or what?

Comment: It not display the city with biggest population.

Comment: If you are still using `document.getData().get("population").toString()`, you won't be able to display anything and simply adding the population number to a list, will not help you at all. So please see my updated answer.

Comment: If you think that my answer from your earlier **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114938/how-to-get-the-id-when-call-add-in-one-step-in-firestore)** was also helpful, you might also consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!